# Real solutions for $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-\sqrt{1+c^2+d^2}>|a-c|+|b-d|$

Tags: inequality

Do there exist real numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that 
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-\sqrt{1+c^2+d^2}>|a-c|+|b-d|?$$

Comment: This is not a site for homework service. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Thanks! It is not a homework question (actually, I am too old for doing homeworks:)The inequality arised from a geometric problem that I was thinking about.

Comment: @Perman You can add that problem to your post. It's expected that you provide some context, not just the problem statement. See the linked post in the 1st comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the points $M=(a,b)$ and $N=(c,d)$. By the triangle inequality
$$OM-ON\leq MN \leq MP+NP $$
which gives us
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-\sqrt{c^2+d^2}\leq MN\leq |a-c|+|b-d| $$
Since $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-\sqrt{1+c^2+d^2}<\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-\sqrt{c^2+d^2} $$ we have the reverse inequality:
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-\sqrt{1+c^2+d^2}<|a-c|+|b-d| $$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's start off with the case $a=b=c=d$. The inequality is false since the RHS is positive, while the LHS is negative.

If we increase or decrease $a$ or $b$, the RHS will increase faster than the LHS since $a$ and $b$ are under the square root sign on the LHS. The inequality will always remain false no matter how we adjust those variables.

If we increase or decrease $c$ or $d$, the RHS will increase and the LHS will decrease. Thus, inequality will still always be false.